# Create a data member vector of polymorphic objects on the heap?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I have an inheritance hierarchy where A is an abstract base class and B and C are polymorphic children.

I wish to have a vector class data member, on the heap, which can contain B and C objects.

So in the header file I have my

```
vector<A*> polymorphicobjs;
```

and in the constructor I tried to do:

```
polymorphicobjs = new vector<A>();
```

but obviously this wouldn't work. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't worry about keeping a `std::vector` of raw pointers. It will create a lot of hassles for you later on making sure you delete objects at the right time. What you should do is store a container of "managed" polymorphic objects (using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)). Declare your vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> polymorphicobjs;
```

And now you can store polymorphic objects in the vector pretty easily (where `B` is a subclass of `A`):

```
polymorphicobjs.push_back(std::unique_ptr<B>(new B));
```

With this, you don't need to ever worry about calling `delete` on the objects in your vector. As soon as you "let go" of the vector (eg, when it goes out of scope in your function or it's automatically destructed if it's a class member), the objects will be deleted. The vector *uniquely* owns the objects.

**But I need to share the objects with other code?!**

If that's the case, then `std::unique_ptr` isn't the right choice. We can express that the objects are *shared* by using `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> polymorphicobjs;
// [...]
polymorphicobjs.push_back(std::make_shared<B>());
```

**Why does the `push_back` look different for unique and shared?**

Because C++14 isn't out yet. If you're lucky enough to use a new enough compiler (bleeding edge clang/gcc/VS2013), the unique version will look very similar:

```
// C++14
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> polymorphicobjs;
// [...]
polymorphicobjs.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
```

Comment: You should be able to replace `push` with `emplace`, where the latter has the benefit of potentially avoiding an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @underscore_d Not necessarily true. `push_back` is overloaded by `T&&` to perform a `move` on the temporary. All the examples in my answer `push_back` temporaries. You will only get a copy if the type doesn't support move semantics, but `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` do. Additionally, for the `std::shared_ptr` example, `emplace` wouldn't know to call `make_shared`. So, you shave a copy at the price of cache locality.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't really considered those nuances. So, when dealing with movable types and containers, is there a convention on which is preferred between `push` and `emplace`? I've been operating on the assumption that `emplace` should be used wherever possible (even if, e.g. for `map`, this requires all the hassle of `piecewise_construct`), but I might've been oversimplifying (probably!)

Comment: @underscore_d Scott Meyers' "Effective Modern C++" speaks on this, at great length, in Item 42. In the end, he recommends preferring emplacement over insertion, so you're not going down the wrong path. That said, a container of (smart) pointers requires either a "naked" `new` or moving a `make_`'ed smart pointer to use emplacement. But, that's no faster than insertion in this case. So, any time a type is created externally from a container (for one reason or another), I prefer insertion over emplacement. In the case of my answer above, that favors `push_back` over `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 2):

I really suggest that you stick to shared_pointers either from the standard if C++11 is an options or the boost ones.

Your basic problem is that you declared a `vector` of pointers not a pointer to a `vector`

```
vector<T*> vec1;// a vector of pointers
vec1.push_back(new T); // add a pointer to our vector

vector<T*>* vec2; //a pointer to a vector of pointers
vec2 = new vector<T>; // create the vector on the heap
vec2->push_back(new T); // add pointer.
```

As I said this is most probably not what you want. You should use smart pointers.

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<B>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do a `new`?

This line:

```
vector<A*> polymorphicobjs;
```

Already initializes your `vector`... After that, you can do:

```
polymorphicobjs.push_back( an_object );
```

---

If you really want to put it on the heap, change your declaration to:

```
vector<A*>* polymorphicobjs;
//        ^
```

But I don't think it is necessary...

Comment: I thought I had to do new to put the vector on the heap?

Comment: @mezamorphic Since your vector is already initialized. There is no need to do a `new`. Why do you want to put it on the heap? Is there a specific need?

Comment: Even if your vector is not on the heap, the objects it contains will be (if they have been allocated on the heap).

Comment: We are foreseeing problems

Comment: @KevinCadieux that does not change the fact, he wants to know how to put vector itself to the heap.

Comment: Putting handle classes such as vector on the heap, which themselves allocate the objects they contain on the heap, is a gratuitous use of dynamic memory. These containers are designed (among other things) to relieve their users of the burden of manual dynamic memory allocation.  I suspect that wanting to new the vector is probably a misconception from the part of mezamorphic that he needs a heap allocated vector to obtain polymorphic behavior.

Comment: When I write a copy constructor for this vector data member, how would I proceed?

Comment: That depends on how you want the copy to behave. If you want to share the same vector among different objects of the class I suppose allocating your vector on the heap would be fine. But in that case I would probably use a [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in order to avoid having to manage the allocation and deallocation myself. But then again, you have to be careful to destroy the actual objects contained in the vector as well because they will not be deleted automatically. In that case you could use an std::vector<std::unique_ptr>

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as you can with any other type:

```
int i = new int; // Error
int *pi = new int; // works!
```

If `vector<A*>` confuses you try to use this:

```
typedef vector<A*> vectorOfA;
vectorOfA v = new vectorOfA; // Error
...                          // guess what will work?
```

So problem that your polymorphicobjs is a vector of pointers, not pointer to such vector.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to new your vector. I suspect you have come from Java, where everything needs a new. C++ is different. Simply having a `vector<A*> polymorphicobjs` in your class is enough to create one. The vector will store its data elements on the heap anyway. You can call its constructor in your class's constructor's initialization list, if you want to. Otherwise it defaults to an empty vector.

To create new objects and put them in the vector:

```
polymorphicobjs.push_back(new B());
```

This will add a new B object to your vector.

You will need to delete them at some point (such as the destructor).

```
for (vector<A*>::iterator it = polymorphicobjs.begin(), end_it = polymorphicobjs.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
{
    delete *it;
}
```

A vector of smart pointers would be better..