# Pointer to array of pointers (dynamic allocation)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am writing a card game in C++. I have a *game* class which keeps track of the players. I also have an abstract base class *player*, from which the classes *person* and *computer* derives.

I would like to keep the players in an array. The number of players is unknown at compile time. Because some players are persons and other computers, I need a player pointer for each, stored in an array, which is dynamically allocated because the number of players is unknown, right?

As I am relatively new to C++, I could not figure out how the syntax looks for this kind of thing.

Comment: You could simplify the problem by using a vector of pointers to Player.

Comment: @juanchopanza Simplify it even more by using a vector of Players rather than pointers (cuz pointers in vectors are kindof the devil).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: This would *slice* the derived objects.

Comment: @Johnsyweb oh yeah your right, didn't notice it was abstract, my bad...

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Right idea, wrong implementation, Use smart pointers if you must store pointers in a `std::vector`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19028239/78845 may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a dynamic array, the standard library provides [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Since you need to store pointers to an abstract base type, rather than the objects themselves, you'll need to make sure you manage the object's lifetimes correctly. The easiest way is to store smart pointers (in this case [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), for simple single ownership), so that objects are automatically destroyed when they're removed from the vector.

So your array would look like

```
// Declaration
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<player>> players;

// Adding players
players.push_back(std::unique_ptr<person>(new person("Human"))); // C++11
players.push_back(std::make_unique<computer>("CPU"));            // C++14 (hopefully)

// Accessing players
for (auto & player : players) {
    player->play();
}
```

Comment: When accessing, what does 'auto' and '&' mean? Also, when I try this in Xcode, it says I need to use '->' instead of '.'

Comment: `auto` means "figure out the type for me"; you could write `player` instead if you wanted. `&` means "reference". Xcode is right: you do need `->` rather than `.` to dereference the smart pointer (I've fixed my answer).

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Player>> players;
```

if you want to use the standard library (which you should)

otherwise

```
Player** players;
```

Comment: Why shared? I see nothing in OP's post to justify that.

Comment: `Player** players` is not an array.

Comment: :) @Johnsyweb . strictly speaking he asked for a pointer to an array, not an array. So you are saying 'Player* is not an array'. You and I know whats behind that statement - he doesn't, so lets not confuse him given that Player * and Player[] will both work fine

Comment: But `Player *` and `Player[]` are not the same thing! Since the OP is "relatively new to C++", it would be better to explain the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a pointer variable using as the following

```
Player *playerptr;
```

It means playerptr is a pointer to type Player.It can hold an address of a Player as well as an array of Players.In C++ and C array is implemented as pointer to the first element of the array.

And as per your requirement you can allocate the array dynamically.

```
playerptr=new Player[20];
```

Here 20 is the size of array.

```
playerptr=new Player[20]();
```

The second syntax will initialize all the elements in the array to their default value.